# NSOutlineViewDelegate - need something like didFinishEditing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

`NSOutlineViewDelegate` has `outlineView:shouldEditTableColumn:item:` which gets called before editing a cell. I need a similar method called after the user has finished editing a cell (in order to trigger some calculations). Where should I look for this event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the `-outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem:` datasource method and you can modify the object that is passed in.